# Relative path to file | Springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, filereader

I am new to Spring-boot/Java and trying to read the contents of a file in a String.

**What's the issue:**
I'm getting "File not found exception" and unable to read the file.  Apparently, I'm not giving the correct file path.

i've attached the directory structure and my code. I'm in **FeedProcessor** file and want to read **feed_template.php** (see image)

```
 public static String readFileAsString( ) {

    String text = "";
    try {
//      text = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("/src/main/template/feed_template_head.php")));

      text = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("../../template/feed_template_head.php")));

    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return text;
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to put template folder inside resource folder. And then use following code.

```
@Configuration
public class ReadFile {

private static final String FILE_NAME =
  "classpath:template/feed_template_head.php";

@Bean
public void initSegmentPerformanceReportRequestBean(
    @Value(FILE_NAME) Resource resource, 
    ObjectMapper objectMapper) throws IOException {

new BufferedReader(resource.getInputStream()).lines()
    .forEach(eachLine -> System.out.println(eachLine));

}
}
```

I suggest you to go though once **Resource** topic in spring.
https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html